# Push Notification not displayed on Android

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have problems getting push notifications to work correctly on Android.

The base system is working fine, the notifications are delivered and received. My test devices play a sound and show the app icon in the status bar at top of screen, and i can view the notification by swiping down.

**But there is no popup shown!**

What do i have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this popup is called ["heads-up notification"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up) and you will get it only for `Notification`s posted on `Channel` with importance set to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` (or high priority `Notification` itself on lower OS versions), according to [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance)

> Example conditions that might trigger heads-up notifications include
> the following:
>
> - The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses fullScreenIntent).
> - The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower.
> - The notification channel has high importance on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher.

Comment: Nice, that did the trick, thank you. I was expecting this to be the default behaviour as on iOS devices.

Comment: When you say a Notifcation posted on "Channel" which channel are you referring to?

Comment: [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Answer (score 1):

Use priority and importance high for notification as specified by: [Heads-up](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up)